# How to parse HTML?

Tags: html-parsing, teradata

I have a table

```
id txt
1  <html> ... a lot of different html tags
2  <html> ... a lot of different html tags
3   <html> ... a lot of different html tags
```

How can I parse `txt` so that I get plain text without all these tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on TD14 you might use REGEXP_REPLACE.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(txt, '<[^>]*>', ' ', 1, 0, 'i')
```

This will return wrong results if you got '<' and '>' within, you should search for a better RegExp then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `REPLACE UDF` which can be downloaded from https://downloads.teradata.com/download/extensibility/teradata-udfs-for-popular-oracle-functions

If you are on TD 14, then it has an inbuilt `REPLACE` function for the same purpose. (www.info.teradata.com/eDownload.cfm?itemid=113480017)